# I need to change some rows to columns from a CSV imported to Python. The CSV has Subheadings

Tags: python, csv, pivot, transpose

This is my original CSV data that Imported into python

| BNS | M1 | M2 | M3 | M1 | M2 | M3 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Creditor | GWP | GWP | GWP | Inf | Inf | Inf |
| Single Prem | 100 | 200 | 300 | 600 | 900 | 50 |
| Double Prem | 200 | 300 | 400 | 330 | 100 | 44 |
| Non Creditor |  |  |  |  |  |  |
| Rent | 33 | 44 | 12 | 75 | 111 | 799 |
| Spouse | 90 | 80 | 86 | 100 | 10 | 100 |

Is there any way to get it like this:

| Product | Months | Category | Value |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Single Prem | M1 | GWP | 100 |
| Single Prem | M2 | GWP | 200 |
| Single Prem | M3 | GWP | 300 |
| Single Prem | M1 | Inf | 600 |
| Single Prem | M2 | Inf | 900 |
| Single Prem | M3 | Inf | 50 |
| Double Prem | M1 | GWP | 200 |
| Double Prem | M2 | GWP | 300 |
| Double Prem | M3 | GWP | 400 |
| Double Prem | M1 | INF | 330 |
| Double Prem | M2 | INF | 100 |
| Double Prem | M3 | INF | 44 |

I made some progress in using

```
df.columns = df.columns.str.extract('(\d+)', expand=False)
df = df.stack().reset_index(name='M').rename(columns={'level_3':'R_no'})
```

But still very far

Comment: We might be able to help you out if you post (a sample of) the original csv in plain text.

Comment: Hey thanks for the quick reply, I edited and changed it to plain text. Really hope this helps thanks again

Answer (score -1):

I have added your first table into a csv file named 'TestCSV.csv'. Below code is generating desired output, you can remove unwanted columns if you want.

```
from ast import If
import pandas as pd
from pandas.core.frame import DataFrame

import csv 

df = pd.read_csv('TestCSV.csv')
print(df.to_string()) 
#print(df.columns)
df = df.drop(0)
df = df.melt(id_vars = ['Product'], var_name = 'Months', value_name = 'Value')
df['Group'] = (
     df.apply(lambda x: 'GWP' if (x.Months == 'M1' or x.Months == 'M2' or x.Months == 'M3') else 'inf', axis=1)
     )
df['NewMonths'] = (
     df.apply(lambda x: x.Months[0:2] if (x.Months == 'M1.1' or x.Months == 'M2.1' or x.Months == 'M3.1') else x.Months, axis=1)
     )
print('\n')
print('Desired output....')
print('\n')
print(df)
```

[image: output of script]

Comment: 1. This doesn't do what OP wants. 2. Saying "use this" and a link to "this" isn't a very good answer. Please see [answer] and [Your answer is in another castle: when is an answer not an answer?](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/225370/174780)